# Get value from previous page to show on current page with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a value from a previous page, and now ran a mysql_query with this value:

```
$sql = "SELECT $value1, $value2 from table where some_value = $previous_page
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[$value1, $value2];
```

In HTML file, I have an input box but I'd like to fill this box first with $value1 when the user sees it.
How can I achieve this?

(and can I echo multiple values like above?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you do a check to see if value actually exists to prevent errors!**

In a row, I would run a PHP check such as:

```
<?php $name = ($value1 != null) ? $value1 : null; ?>
// This checks if it exists, and either returns the value or nothing if it doesn't exist.
```

Then in HTML, I would have a form (either a new one or the same one):

```
<input type="text" name="value1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
<!-- This allows it to either place value in the text box, or does nothing if it doesn't exist. -->
```

I gave you the code supposing you know how to direct it to the form and whatnot. I tried to skip the semantics as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option could be to use $_GET['value'].

ie.

```
$previousvalue = $_GET['value'];

<input value="<?= $previousvalue;?>">
```

in you dont like that way, and the user is logged in, you could save the $previousvalue in a sql table and fetch it with:

```
mysql_select_db("table");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = $_SESSION['email']");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
$defaultvalue = $row['defaultvalue'];
}
```

and then run your original code

```
$sql = "SELECT $value1, $value2 from table where some_value = $defaultvalue
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[$value1, $value2];
```